# Think simple issue with google api. Init 2 Libraries

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I'm trying to init 2 libraries (adsense and places) in one line

I try this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.pl/maps/api/js?sensor=true&language=pl&amp;output=embed&libraries=adsense;libraries=places"></script>
```

And this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.pl/maps/api/js?sensor=true&language=pl&amp;output=embed&libraries=adsense&libraries=places"></script>
```

But this isn't working:( How it should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries.html says:

> Multiple libraries may be specified as a comma-separated list.

So try `adsense,places`, ie.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.pl/maps/api/js?sensor=true&language=pl&amp;output=embed&libraries=adsense,places"></script>
```